# add different links according to product ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

For woocommerce, I have the following code that adds a linked button in my account orders list based on the status of the order:

```
function sv_add_my_account_order_actions( $actions, $order ) {

// only add our button if the order is paid for
// if using WC 2.5+, can simplify this to: if ( ! $order->is_paid() )

if ( ! ( $order->has_status( 'briefing' ) ) ) {
    return $actions;
}  

$actions['briefing'] = array(
    // adjust URL as needed
    'name' => __( 'Responder Briefing', 'my-textdomain' ),
    'url'  => 'https://link1.com/order=' . $order->get_order_number(), 
);

return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'sv_add_my_account_order_actions', 10, 2 );
```

I would like this link to change according to the product ID included in that order, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It did not work with me. It is taking the URL below:

```
$ actions ['briefing'] = array (
         // adjust URL as needed
         'url' => 'https://link1.com/order='. $ order-> get_order_number (),
         'name' => __ ('Reply Briefing', 'my-textdomain'),
     );
```